# Object changes after being pushed to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The object `y` being pushed to the array `data` below. The object that ends up in the array called data is different from the object that is being pushed - what is causing this error?

```
export const fetchSP500 = (year) => {
    let data = [];
    let cumulativeReturn = 1;

    SP500.reverse().forEach(y=>{
        cumulativeReturn *= ((y.totalReturn*.01)+1)

        y.cumulativeReturn = ((cumulativeReturn -1) * 100);

        if(y.year >= year[0] && y.year <= year[1]) {
            console.log('y:', y)
            data.push(y)
            console.log('data:', data)
        }

    })
    
    return data;

}
```

Original array:

```
const SP500 = [
    {
    "year": 2020,
    "totalReturn": 18.40
    },
    {
    "year": 2019,
    "totalReturn": 31.49
    },
    {
    "year": 2018,
    "totalReturn": -4.38
    },
    {
    "year": 2017,
    "totalReturn": 21.83
    }]
```

Expected log:

```
y: {year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}
data: [{year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}]
y: {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 16.49384599999999}
data: [{year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}, {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 16.49384599999999}]
y: {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 53.177758105399974}
data: [{year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}, {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 16.49384599999999}, {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 53.177758105399974}]
y: {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
data: [{year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}, {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 16.49384599999999}, {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 53.177758105399974}, {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}]
```

Actual log:

```
y: 
{year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 21.829999999999995}
main.chunk.js:334 data: 
[{…}]
0: {year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
1: {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 48.865193791999985}
2: {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 55.684159999999984}
3: {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 18.399999999999995}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
main.chunk.js:332 y: 
{year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 16.49384599999999}
main.chunk.js:334 data: 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
1: {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 48.865193791999985}
2: {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 55.684159999999984}
3: {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 18.399999999999995}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
main.chunk.js:332 y: 
{year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 53.177758105399974}
main.chunk.js:334 data: 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
1: {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 48.865193791999985}
2: {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 55.684159999999984}
3: {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 18.399999999999995}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
main.chunk.js:332 y: 
{year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
main.chunk.js:334 data: 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {year: 2017, totalReturn: 21.83, cumulativeReturn: 81.36246559679357}
1: {year: 2018, totalReturn: -4.38, cumulativeReturn: 48.865193791999985}
2: {year: 2019, totalReturn: 31.49, cumulativeReturn: 55.684159999999984}
3: {year: 2020, totalReturn: 18.4, cumulativeReturn: 18.399999999999995}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I run your code. The result like expected log.
[image]